# Timeout Error Connecting to Teradata Server From SSIS using Attunity Driver - "[WSock32 DLL] 10060 WSA E TimedOut"

Tags: windows, ssis, timeout, teradata, attunity

I'm facing an issue connecting to Teradata from SSIS using Attunity connector. My environment details as follows:

- Windows 2016
- SQL Server 2016 (Enterprise Edition)
- VS 2015
- Attunity Driver 5.0
- Teradata drivers installed - 15.10.05

When I run the package from the server (both via Agent as well as from BIDS) following is the error I'm getting:

> "Error: There was an error trying to establish an Open Database
>   Connectivity (ODBC) connection with the database server. SqlState =
>   HYT00 Message = [WSock32 DLL] 10060 WSA E TimedOut: No response
>   received when attempting to connect to the Teradata server"

Is there any server level configuration or network settings, I need to enable? Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!!